# Pourquoi est-ce que "crypter" est souvent considéré comme une faute?

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique

De nombreux articles (par exemple [ici](https://www.seald.io/blog/crypter-un-fichier-chiffrer-proteger-qui-dit-quoi) et [ici](https://chiffrer.info)) condamnent l'utilisation du verbe "crypter" dans le sens de "cacher des informations au moyen d'un code".

Mais j'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi :

- étymologiquement, kryptos signifie caché en grec donc le sens n'a pas changé,
- dans l'usage, crypter semble être largement utilisé.

Les seuls arguments que je vois sont de la forme "non, on ne dit pas ça, sinon ça voudrait dire quelque chose d'absurde, chiffrer sans savoir déchiffrer". Mais cela voudrait-il dire cela en fait ? Tout cela me semble être une vague de purisme sans aucun fondement. Y a-t-il une raison linguistique ?

Comment: Du purisme sans fondement n'est pas du purisme, c'est des fantaisies, des lubies, des caprices,…On peut au plus  parler de purisme exagéré.

Comment: Cela dépend de ce que tu appelles purisme, mais oui l'on se comprend

Comment: TLFi : **purisme**  Rejet de tout ce qui va contre le bon usage linguistique.

Comment: Larousse: encrypter, en informatique, voilà pourquoi.

Comment: *Encrypter* ne concerne que les ***mots de passe*** que l'ont ne peut pas *déchiffrer*, même si on connaît l'algorithme qui les ont cryptés, on ne peut que comparer les résultats (celui dans le coffre-fort du serveur et celui tapé par un quidam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoir une étymologie valable n'est ni nécessaire, ni suffisant pour qu'un mot soit considéré comme « correct » ou du moins peu contestable. Il doit d'abord faire ses preuves à l'usage.

La première raison pour laquelle utiliser le verbe ***crypter*** a été et est encore parfois considéré comme une faute de français est que ce mot n'existait pas, ou du moins n'était quasiment pas attesté avant le milieu du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, et surtout qu'il fait double emploi avec un verbe existant bien établi.

Depuis très longtemps, on dispose en effet des verbes ***chiffrer*** et ***déchiffrer*** pour désigner l'action de transformer un message en quelque chose d'illisible et vice-versa. Les équivalents anglais sont les verbes ***cipher*** et ***decipher*** qui, via le français et l'italien, viennent de l'arabe *sifr* (zéro). La science qui concerne ces techniques est appelée ***cryptographie***, un mot qui existe depuis longtemps puisqu'on le trouve par exemple dans la Bibliographie politique du Sieur Naudé, publié en 1642 :

[image]

Le grec ***kryptos*** a, via le latin *crypta*, d'abord donné le mot français ***cropte*** (ou ***croupte***) qui désignait les lieux souterrains où l'on pouvait se cacher, mot qui a évolué en deux formes encore utilisées, l'évolution de *cropte* en ***grotte*** et la forme savante et spécialisée ***crypte*** (église souterraine). On ne trouvait pas de verbe dérivé tel que *grotter* et quasiment pas de *crypter*. La seule occurrence que j'ai pu trouver se trouve dans l'extrait suivant, où *se crypter* signifie « se cacher (dans une crypte) ».

[image]

Le néologisme *décrypter* est apparu au début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, et désignait le travail consistant à essayer de retrouver le sens des messages interceptés dont on ne connaissait pas la méthode de chiffrement.

En voici une des premières apparitions (Le Génie civil : revue générale des industries françaises et étrangères, 1922)

[image]

Le décryptage est une opération difficile puisqu'on ne connait pas l'algorithme qui a servi à créer le document. Il n'y a pas d'opération inverse puisque quand on chiffre un document, on sait quelle méthode on a choisi.

Aujourd'hui, la situation a changé et le verbe ***crypter*** est très souvent utilisé pour traduire l'anglais *encrypt*, en particulier dans un contexte informatique (par exemple dans « crypter un fichier ») mais chiffrer semble encore bien se défendre :

[image]

En France, l'adjectif *crypté* a été popularisé en 1985 avec l'arrivée de Canal+. Jean-Denis Bredin (académicien) parle de *chaîne **cryptée*** dans un rapport au premier ministre écrit cette année là. Personne ne disait *chaîne chiffrée* qui aurait trop évoqué une histoire d'espionnage. Les équipements techniques utilisés n'utilisent ni ***chiffrer***, ni ***crypter*** mais ***coder***. On parle d'encoder le signal chez le diffuseur et les téléspectateurs utilisent des ***décodeurs***.

Un avantage de ***crypter*** par rapport à ***chiffrer*** est que ce dernier  a un autre sens bien distinct (calculer un coût), ce que montre le NGram ci-dessus alors que le premier n'est pas ambigu.

L'anglais ne fait plus de distinction entre [*decrypt* et *decipher*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/difference-between-decryption-and-deciphering).

Comment: Permettez-moi d'ajouter quelque éléments complémentaires : l'équivalent en langue courante de "décrypter" serait "casser le code". Pour le terme "crypter", j'attribue son regain (~1980) à l'arrivée de canal+ : le terme habituel pour la désigner était "chaîne cryptée" et l'on parlait souvent du "cryptage" de cette chaîne.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, j'étais justement en train d'ajouter un paragraphe sur Canal+.

Answer (score -4):

C'est certainement une affaire de purisme, mais d'un purisme tout nouveau, celui qui exige que le sens du mot soit strictement fidèle à sa racine. Il se trouve que les mots qui enfreignent ce principe abondent dans le français moderne.

- **[agoniser](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agoniser)** empr. au lat. chrét. agonizare « lutter » (Vulgate, I épitre de Paul aux Corinthiens 9, 25 ds Blaise 1954 : omnis qui agonizat);
- **[château](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chateau)**  Du lat. castellum (dimin. de castrum « camp ») attesté dans la lang. class. au sens de « redoute »
- **[robe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/robe)** Déverbal de l’ancien français rober (« voler ») dont est issu l’anglais rob et qui ne subsiste plus que sous forme préfixée dérober. Ce mot a eu pour sens « butin de guerre », « dépouille » puis, par spécialisation, « tunique » et enfin, par hyperspécialisation, « vêtement féminin ».

L'Académie et certaines organisations prétendent que le sens diverge de la racine grecque, ce qui est vrai puisque du point de vue d'une interprétation stricte l'idée de correspondance est perdue : en effet, il n'est plus question que de rendre inaccessible la vrai signification, sans mentionner qu'un moyen est donné pour inverser le procédé. La divergence n'est pas plus grande que celle qu'on peut lire dans le passage de « castrum » (camp) à « château » (forteresse). Dans le sens d'instaurer de nouvelles notions prescriptives d'étymologie selon lesquelles le sens est dérivé strictement de la racine, il est clair qu'une inexactitude est introduite. Cependant, on ne parle nulle part de telles notions, elles font partie d'un idéal sans véritable consensus, et on sait que quantités de mots qui pénètrent dans le langage en permanence ne  sont pas analysés de cette façon, mais  qu'ils prennent naissance par création plus ou moins spontanée qu'une définition de dictionnaire devra plus tard étayer, et cela pas selon le strict sens d'une  racine mais finalement selon l'usage. Au regard de cette situation, appliquer des préceptes idéalisés dans la justification du mot « crypter » est d'un arbitraire peu compréhensible ; il a, après tout, fait ses preuves selon le procédé habituel et il est défini selon l'usage, comme le montre le Wiktionnaire.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crypter) (Cryptographie) Chiffrer, coder une information afin de la rendre incompréhensible à toute personne ignorant la méthode ou la clé de chiffrement.
> ♦  Crypter, c’est transformer un texte clair en un texte inintelligible dit texte crypté. — (Claude Palmeti, Lena Mirlova, Rennes-Le-Château, Une autre approche de l’énigme, Publibook, page 117, 2001)

Remarquer que la définition du Wiktionnaire considère bien que l'idée qu'une correspondance doit être fournie.

Au regard d'une politique consistante de la préservation d'une étymologie fidèle au sens, il n'est pas question de purisme extravagant, mais bien simplement de purisme. Au vu de l'absence évidente d'une telle politique ce n'est plus une question de purisme mais une question d'arbitraire complet dans les pratiques linguistiques. Ce que le mot signifie en fin de compte c'est ce que l'utilisateur a pensé qu'il signifie et que l'on détermine à partir du contexte dans lequel il a inséré ce mot, rien d'autre, et cette détermination est toujpours faite, même de nos jours, bien longtemps après que le mot a suffisamment été utilisé.

Si on considère maintenant le candidat que certain tiennent pour idéal en tant que représentant de ce concept informatique (plus généralement un concept de correspondance secrète), c'est à dire  « chiffrer », est-ce que la racine de celui-ci le définit parfaitement ? Pas du tout ! Il a l'étymologie suivante lorsqu'il est attesté pour la première fois en 1574.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chiffrer)) **Étymol. et Hist.** **1.** 1515 « calculer à l'aide de chiffres » (Lortie, Arithm. ds DG); 1611 chiffré « calculé » (Cotgr.); **2.** 1574 « écrire (un message) avec un chiffre » (Lettre de M. Stuart à l'archevêque de Glasgow ds Gdf. Compl.)

De « calculer » à « utiliser selon une correspondance » il y a un monde de différence. « Chiffrer » n'est pas plus pur étymologiquement, au contraire.

On voit de plus qu'aucun terme ne sera étymologiquement fidèle à sa morphologie, à moins de beaucoup de chance (existence d'un élément formant approprié) ou de beaucoup de créativité de la part de ceux qui choisissent les mots.

En conclusion, je pense devoir dire que selon l'approche  contemporaine à la création du vocabulaiure, qui, soit dit en passant, est celle de tous les temps, il n'y a pratiquement pas de justification de ce qui serait l'impropriété de « crypter » du point de vue de son étymologie.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse détaillée et éclairante